# Migrating to TypeScript. How to break long Revealing Module Patterns into partials?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iife

Trying to migrate some JS code to TypeScript. We have a number of JavaScript files written as Revealing Module Patterns. Here is a reduction of the pattern:

```
var thing = (function() {
    var var1, var2;
    function init() {
        var1 = document.getElementById("var1");
        var2 = document.getElementById("var2");
        function func1() {
            // really long function that needs access to var1
        }
        function func2() {
            // really long function that needs access to var2
        }
    }
    // Our Bootstrap file fires this when ready
    BootStrap.DOMReady(init);
    return {
        Func1: func1,
        Func2: func2,
    };
})();
```

However, currently `func1` and `func2` are really long functions that we would like to 'partial' into their own `func1.ts` and `func2.ts` files for easier maintenance. However, they need access to the vars of the init.

What is the best way to achieve this kind of functionality? Ideally we want smaller `.ts` files for individual functions that we can bring into a `main.ts` file.

Do we need to go the import/export route?

Could we achieve this with triple slash directives and somehow keep scope (unsure as the inner functions need to keep function scope and triple slash seem to need to be defined at the start of a file)?

Is it even possible to do something like this?

```
var thing = (function() {
    function init() {
        /// <reference path="ts/func1.ts" />
        /// <reference path="ts/func2.ts" />
    }
    // Our Bootstrap file fires this when ready
    BootStrap.DOMReady(init);
    return {
        Func1: func1,
        Func2: func2,
    };
})();
```

Comment: what is really init doing? defining the functions there isn't doing anything at all - like it is now you can move the functions outside into the same scope as "var thing", right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine modules from other files you may look into export..from and do something like this in main.ts:

`export { Func1 } from './ts/func1.ts'; 
export { Func2 } from './ts/func2.ts';`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Since you are not executing the functions you can do something like this(here using commonJs module system)

```
import { func1 } from './ts/func1.ts'; 
import { func2 } from './ts/func2.ts';

var thing = (function() {
    function init() {
        // init logic
        func1.bind(this); func2.bind(this);
    }
    // Our Bootstrap file fires this when ready
    BootStrap.DOMReady(init);
})();

export { func1 as Func1, func2 as Func2 }
```

if you can't use that, you can just reference the files in top, and return/export it at bottom after thing has ran.

```
/// <reference path="ts/func1.ts" />
/// <reference path="ts/func2.ts" />

var thing = (function() {
    function init() {
        // init logic
        func1.bind(this); func2.bind(this);
    }
    // Our Bootstrap file fires this when ready
    BootStrap.DOMReady(init);
})();

return { Func1: func1, Func2: func2 } // func1/2 has to imported from you external files
```

Comment: I've updated the post, I failed to mention that the functions we want to 'partial' need access to things within function scope that contains them. We also want to ensure that `func1` and `func2` are private functions. The revealing module pattern facilitates that but we would like to break out the internal functions into different files for maintenance.

Comment: ok, but they are not private since you are returning them. anyway, you could do a "func1.bind(this)" inside your init to make sure they can access stuff inside that scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ES6 import/export sounds like a viable solution:

```
// thing/init.js
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
export var var1, var2;
function init() {
    var1 = document.getElementById("var1");
    var2 = document.getElementById("var2");
// Our Bootstrap file fires this when ready
BootStrap.DOMReady(init);
```

```
// thing/func1.js
import {var1} from './init';
export default function func1() {
    // really long function that needs access to var1
}
```

```
// thing/func2.js
import {var2} from './init';
export default function func2() {
    // really long function that needs access to var2
}
```

```
// thing.js
import func1 from 'thing/func1';
import func2 from 'thing/func2';
export {
    func1 as Func1,
    func2 as Func2
}
// you can also default-export an object but better shouldn't
```

Comment: Won't this need a module loader to work in the browser though? TypeScript supports Node modules by default but presumably for functionality in the browser a module loader would be needed (which I would like to avoid, hence TypeScript)

Comment: A module bundler will be enough - and you cannot really avoid that if you want to put your code in different files